# iCloud restore issue on iPhone 4S

Tags: icloud, restore

I had a minor problem with my iPhone so I decided to restore from the most recent iCloud backup. I assumed it worked much like system restore on my laptop.  After resetting the phone and following the instructions, I began the restore from a backup less than 12 hours old. I got a message saying that there was a problem with the backup and I should choose another source.  I attempted backups from all three most recent backups and got the same message. Is there anything besides a corrupted backup file that would cause this? I do have an iTunes backup but I haven't been as diligent about those since I thought that the iCloud backup was reliable. So if I restore to the iTunes backup I'll lose some data that I really don't want to lose (ideas, work notes, etc.) Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar error on my iPhone 4S while restoring an iCloud backup. I fixed it by simply updating the firmware/iOS version to the latest version available from Apple. Latest iOS 7.1.2 was out at that time but I was running outdated iOS 7.0.4. Once the phone restored with the latest iOS version, I was able to restore from iCloud. So update your iOS if you're using an older iOS version and try again.

Comment: The phone had the latest iOS and is updated now. Manually reconstructed the phone and apps then did another iCloud backup AND an iTunes backup... the latest iCloud backup failed again. I'd like to recover some notes and voice recordings but I'm beginning to lose hope...will not depend on iCloud backup from here on out. Apple should at least have some way of warning users that backups are corrupted and not useable before you have to use it.